# Making custom object convertible

Tags: java, casting

In java is it possible for me to design my own class to be convertible(or castable?) to a primitive type? For example, if I have:

```
Class IntString{
  private int intVal;
  private String strVal;

  public IntString(int intVal, String strVal){
    this.intVal = intVal;
    this.strVal = strVal;
  }
}

static void main(String[] args){
  IntString intStr = new IntString(1,"yes");
}
```

is it possible to have something like:

```
int intTstVal = intStr;
```

or even

```
int intTstVal = (int)intStr;
```

?

And also can I make the class work with String in the same fashion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Not implicitly however you can implements the same/similar methods to those the wrappers use.

```
int intTstVal = intStr.intValue();

String text = intStr.stringValue();
```

Comment: Hi Peter, Thanks for your reply. But that is VERY obvious. This is not 'convertible' or 'casting'.

Answer (score -1):

No. You're apparently trying to emulate a loosely-typed language like PHP, Javascript or Python, but Java is not such a language. With base types, what you're trying to do is not possible. You might be able to fiddle around with generic methods and casts and the like, but I don't think that's the best solution.

What exactly are you trying to achieve here, by the way?

Comment: Apologies for the late answer guys. Cthulhu may be right. What I want to do is to create a custom Enum. I know enum is there. But it is not available for MIDP2.0. I still can progress upto some extent; but can not use them in switch case statements. An eample would be:

Comment: `public final class MyEnum{
    private final int code;
    private final String desc;
    
    private MyEnum(final int code, final String desc){
        this.code = code;
        this.desc = desc;
    }
    
    public int getCode(){
        return code;
    }
    
    public String getDesc(){
        return desc;
    }
    
    public static MyEnum VAL1 = new MyEnum(0,"Val1");
    public static MyEnum VAL2 = new MyEnum(2,"Val2");
}
`